# Windows Powershell frequently hangs running jboss 7.1.1

Tags: java, powershell, web-applications, jboss, powershell-3.0

I am new to jboss server level configuration. Our application is hosted in windows server and running through power shell. Once in a day power shell got hanged and we are restarting the jboss server.

Heap memory
-Xms1024m
-Xmx8192m
32 GB RAM
Please let me know if you required any other configuration to identify the issue.

Help us to identify the root cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the reason might be clicking inside Windows Power Shell, makes the power shell to wait and the cascade effect makes all the threads wait and finally results in server hung.

Reason: 
Clicking inside the windows power shell, knowingly or unknowingly it stops the output in the console and also the output to the log file. This could hold the thread which tries to write the log and hence we have other threads waiting.

Solution:

Temporary: 
Once any key is pressed on the windows power shell, 
it releases the console output and log and hence all the threads are released.

Permanent:

Uncheck the properties QuickEdit Mode and\or Insert in the windows power shell, this will not have any impact on our application, as we don’t need this feature enabled for our window power shell. [Please read this blog](https://serverfault.com/questions/204150/sometimes-powershell-stops-sending-output-until-i-press-enter-why).

Answer (score 0):

Check this link to tune the perfomance of JBoss AS 7

[Performance tuning](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-performance/jboss-as-7-performance-tuning?showall=&start=1)